# Everyone, my cgroup restricts the maximum amount of memory that users can use and does not work

Tags: cgroups

I want to use libcgroup Tools to write cgconfig.conf and cgrules.conf files to limit the maximum memory usage of different users, but it has no effect. I repeatedly restarted cgconfig and cgrid, but it didn't work.
in cgconfig.conf：

```
group users_mem_limit{
        memory{
                memory.limit_in_bytes = 1G;
                memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes = 1G;
        }
}

template users/%u {
        memory {
                memory.limit_in_bytes = 2G;
                memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes = 2G;
        }
}
```

in cgrules.conf：

```
user1               memory          users_mem_limit/
*                   memory,cpu      users/%u
```

I repeatedly restarted the cgconfig and cgrid services, but there was no response. My virtual machine has a maximum memory limit of 7GB, but my stress test will not return an error on 3G, only on 7GB or above. Even if I use the wrong user, I should still report an error on 3G. I don't understand where the problem lies

```
stress -m 1 --vm-bytes 3G -t 2
```